# Reducing Output from two UNION queries, too many resulting rows currently

Tags: sql-server, merge, union

SQL Server : here is my basic query. I can't figure out how to properly make this "result" only show one row per store/date, the two queries each fill in columns 3 and 4. Right now the result is giving me 2 rows per store/date with NULL in opposing columns.  It should only be one row per store/date with an occasional NULL remaining third column.

```
DECLARE @START DATETIME, @END DATETIME
SET @END   = CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS DATETIME) + '03:00'
SET @START = @END - 7

SELECT 
    @START [From], @END [To]

SELECT 
    DivisionName, DateClosed, COUNT(OrderId) AS PREDATED, NULL AS DAYOF 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         o.OrderId, DivisionName, DateCreated, 
         CONVERT(Date, DateClosed) [DateClosed]   
     FROM 
         POS.Orders o WITH(NOLOCK)
     JOIN 
         POS.OrderDetails od WITH(NOLOCK) ON o.OrderId = od.OrderId
     JOIN 
         Directory.Divisions d WITH(NOLOCK) ON o.DivisionId = d.DivisionId
     WHERE 
         DateClosed BETWEEN @START AND @END AND DateCreated < @START) t
 GROUP BY 
     DivisionName, DateClosed

 UNION

 SELECT 
     DivisionName, DateClosed, NULL AS PREDATED, COUNT(OrderID) AS DAYOF
 FROM 
     (SELECT 
          o.OrderId, DivisionName, DateCreated, 
          CONVERT(Date,DateClosed)[DateClosed]
      FROM 
          POS.Orders o WITH(NOLOCK)
      JOIN 
          POS.OrderDetails od WITH(NOLOCK) ON o.OrderId = od.OrderId
      JOIN 
          Directory.Divisions d WITH(NOLOCK) ON o.DivisionId = d.DivisionId
      WHERE 
          DateClosed BETWEEN @START AND @END AND DateCreated >= @START) s
GROUP BY 
    DivisionName, DateClosed
```

[image: SQL results]

Comment: Just use `;WITH t as (<your query>) SELECT DivisionName, DateClosed, MAX(PREDATED) AS PREDATED, MAX(DAYOF) AS DAYOF FROM t GROUP BY DivisionName, DateClosed;` ;).

Comment: You can simplify your query by only selecting the dataset _once_ for the full date range, then use a case statement inside the `COUNT` to pick out the date ranges you want to count for. When you repeat code like that there is usually a better way to do it. I will post more details if you're interested

Comment: shA.t - The ;with t suggestion above worked perfectly.  Now I need to read up and understand WHY so that I replicate this technique knowledgably in the future.  If you add this as an ANSWER I will vote it upwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a structure like this:

```
;WITH t as (
    <your query>
) 
SELECT DivisionName, DateClosed, MAX(PREDATED) AS PREDATED, MAX(DAYOF) AS DAYOF 
FROM t 
GROUP BY DivisionName, DateClosed;
```

---

I don't have your sample data, But you can use a query like this:

```
SELECT 
     DivisionName, CONVERT(Date, DateClosed) [DateClosed],
     COUNT(CASE WHEN DateClosed BETWEEN @START AND @END AND DateCreated < @START THEN 0 END) AS PREDATED,
     COUNT(CASE WHEN DateClosed BETWEEN @START AND @END AND DateCreated >= @START THEN 0 END) AS DAYOF
 FROM 
     POS.Orders o WITH(NOLOCK)
 JOIN 
     POS.OrderDetails od WITH(NOLOCK) ON o.OrderId = od.OrderId
 JOIN 
     Directory.Divisions d WITH(NOLOCK) ON o.DivisionId = d.DivisionId
 GROUP BY 
     DivisionName, DateClosed
```

Comment: This looked wonderfully promising, but resulted in 100s of thousands of individual rows since the BETWEEN stuff didn't manage to exclude orders outside the range.

Comment: I tried moving the WHERE DateClosed BETWEEN .... further down before the GROUP BY, which worked, but this resulted in 12000 rows of correct individual results, worse than when I started, trying to get my two original SUM results to merge down even more.

Comment: Why you think second solution is worse? as performance issues second one is better!? And also as readability issues!?

Comment: Yes, the second one looks fabulous visually and logically.  But the results are 12000 individual rows for the same date range.  The first one using my original query and your semicolon syntax reduced my 160 interlaced rows down to 92 merged rows, perfect. [link](http://content.screencast.com/users/JerryBeaucaire/folders/Jing/media/cfe173d2-12a9-4cbe-a27b-613c47d0adb4/2016-12-14_0725.png)